# how to indent a div in the index.jade with node.js expressjs?

Tags: node.js, html, express, pug

i have an index.jade that have a div with nothing
this div called div_one it supose to be dynamic div so i change the content with a button
so i have 4 divs prepared in .jade to replace de content of div_one

i want to put some divs on that div when i push a button

```
#div_one
    //nothing
```

when i push the button the div_one change

```
#div_one
    #div_in_1
        t some text
    #div_in_2
        t other text data
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may want to use separate requests for this, i.e. AJAX. The server side code would be:

```
app.get('/div_in_1', function(req, res) {
    res.render('div_in_1.jade');
}

// For every div
```

The front-end code would be:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/div_in_1",
    }).done(function(msg) { 
        $('#div_one').html(msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! it works! but i have some errors in jade so i will try to fix that but apparently this is the answer! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this has to do with indenting, but something like this works (I use jQuery here)...

```
script
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#div_one').html('<div id="div_in_1">t some text</div><div id="div_in_2">t other text data</div>');
    });

#div_one
    | empty

button#btn Click me
```

Comment: thanks johnson but that is html code... i want to do same thing with jade code... i repeat i have 4 archives.jade each one has some content in jade... i want to replace the content of #div_one with those files depends witch button was pressed...

Comment: Your initial question needs to be clearer. You made no mention of multiple Jade files there. Look at user1306716's answer.

Comment: i was trying to be clearly but my english is too bad! thanks for your time sorry for my english!